# d3.js pushing object into another object which has array of object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I already have object(called callbackData) which already has [Object,Object,Object,Object] structure.(these are real Object).
When I push in callbackData1(which is also object) into callbackData and then look into callbackData, I see that callbackData1 object was pushed in as Array(while previous object remain object).

What am I missing here? Am I pushing this in the wrong way?

```
console.log("callbackData type is  " + typeof(callbackData));
console.log("creating --------------------> " + typeof(callbackData1));
console.log("pushing data in"); 
     callbackData.push(callbackData1);
```

Comment: you can't push into an object, only an array

Comment: that really is terrible as I need to be able to do push and shift operation in order to update the line chart in d3.js.. hmmm

Comment: D3 works with arrays of objects not objects containing objects. So this way will work fine

Comment: I guess I really just don't understand this thing too well.

callbackData is an object w/ structure like [ object,object,object,object]. Why can't I just push in another object? It seems like I can shift things from it but not push?(that is push another object and not an array).

Comment: Your callbackData in that instance is not an object, it is an array. I know this because the square brackets represent array ([ ]), where as an object is curly braces ({ }). So you can use callbackData.push(object to push here)

Comment: but when I do typeof(callbackData), I get back "object"

Comment: Check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996871/why-does-typeof-array-with-objects-return-object-and-not-array or here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array

Comment: Okay, so I don't know if that is terribly good news(array is actually type of an object, which means I cannot truly find out if something is pure array?).  But then okay, now I am going back to my original problem. callbackData is an array which contains objects. I cannot push another object into this array? I am so sorry for going around and around but I just haven't found the right explanation.

Comment: yes you can push as callbackData is an array not an object. So callbackData.push(placeObjectToPushHere) will work

Comment: I will try it again but when I do that, I got callbackData = ["object',"object","object","array"]  when I want newly created object that I just pushed in to go in as "object".

Comment: show example code, preferably get a JSFiddle together and ill take a look

Comment: Data gets read from mysql    https://jsfiddle.net/askingquestionsagain/nr6ztspf/

Comment: Can you not just mock it up ?

Comment: will try right now.. thanks for your help

Comment: my mockup sounds like it should work but my data generation and assigning to data is not working the way it should when I use d3.json

Comment: sorry, just cannot convert d3.json feed right into the html page. I will just have to work on this w/ real data.. really appreciate your help though!

Comment: I am not crazy about this but I was able to get around this particular problem by converting the array into object. Still not updating properly but this particular issue is done now.    for ( var i = 0 ; i < mycallbackData1Length; i++){
             callbackData.push(callbackData1[i]);
}

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.concat()` instead of `.push()`, as it sounds like you need to join two arrays-of-objects.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

Specifically, try:

```
callbackData = callbackData.concat(callbackData1);
```

Instead of:

```
callbackData.push(callbackData1);
```

Comment: This actually looks like it did push the object into the array(so that is success in that way) but overall is still not working. but thank you for this idea!