# Different type name in console for build-in object types in js

Tags: javascript, object, types, prototype

I was trying to get used to constructor functions and the protype chain, and I basically got inheritance and everything to work... I was wondering though, if there's something wrong with my way of creating objects of "new types": If I let firefox run this code:

```
function Point() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

var a = new Array();
var b = new Date();
var c = new Point();

console.log(typeof a,a);
console.log(typeof b,b);
console.log(typeof c,c);
```

...the console will output:

[image]

As you can see, even though all of them are basically objects, for a it says *Array*, for b *Date*, but for c only *Object* instead of *Point*

My question now is: Is this just a thing of the console, of build-in functions or can I get my point to be a *Point*?

Comment: try `console.log(c.prototype.name)` to get the class name. own defined objects are allways displayed as Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these questions:

- [How do I get the name of an object's type in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript)
- [Why does typeof array with objects return "Object" and not "Array"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12996871/147507)

You're basically on the right track, but the object **type** is not quite the same as the object class name, which is what you're looking for.