# Why an Array property of an Object always returns object

Tags: javascript, object

How do i convert object property to array and use it like array ?
I would like to access an array which is a property of an Object. But It's returned as an Object.

I don't have to check if its type is an array. But i want to iterate over it like we do for normal javascript array.

```
var obj = {PhaseId: "", OptionDescription: "", PhaseDescription: "", 'ClassId': ['test','test1] };

console.log( typeof obj.classId) // return obj
```

Comment: An array is an object. If you want to check, if a property is an array use `obj.prop instanceof Array`.

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996871/why-does-typeof-array-with-objects-return-object-and-not-array

Comment: Basically you can't. Because array elements contains only numeric key. And Object elements can be (string, Numeric, boolean...). So you can all Array kind of Object but Object is not an Array.

Comment: It'd help if your syntax was correct.

Comment: Which property are you trying to "convert"? The `ClassId` property is already an array...

Comment: Use `Array.isArray`

Comment: @Rajesh OP isn't asking how to check, but "how to convert", even though their example shows them type checking. They need to be more clear in their problem statement.

Comment: @evolutionxbox True. I thought OP is looking for a way to get `Array` as output for `typeof`

Comment: @amit Add more context to your question. Do you want to "convert", or "check the type"? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: so if i now iterate over that array using .map i am returning boolean value, but it is returning an array. But i want to just return boolean value with some comparision.

Answer (score 1):

Like this (you have a typo in your sample btw)

```
var obj = {
    PhaseId: "", 
    OptionDescription: "", 
    PhaseDescription: "", 
    classId: ['test','test1'] }; 
console.log( obj.classId[1]);  // logs "test1"
```

Comment: Answering on fresh SO questions is fierce!

Comment: I didn't down vote. Your answer makes sense to an unfinished question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically You are getting Object. Because array elements contains only numeric key. And Object elements can be (string, Numeric, boolean, obejct and array). Here your inside `obj` element `ClassId` is another array. And an Array is also an Object. That's why you are getting `object`.

So you can all Array kind of Object but Object is not an Array.

Also in your example you made one mistake, you used `classId` like `'classId'`.  when you call `classID` like `var classId = obj.classId` then this `classId` behave like an array and it's element index start from `0`. To check it's array or not use `Array.isArray(classId)`:

```js
    var obj = {
        PhaseId: "", 
        OptionDescription: "", 
        PhaseDescription: "", 
        classId: ['test','test1'] }; 
    var classId = obj.classId;
    console.log(Array.isArray(classId)); // returns boolean
    console.log(classId[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

the `typeof` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is deceiving, and only tells you `object` for arrays (because it *technically* is an object).

Use `Array.isArray()` to test for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Like Rahul Amin said in his answer array is an object but object is not always array.

```
    var obj = {
  "array": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "boolean": true,
  "null": null,
  "number": 123,
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  },
  "string": "Hello World"
};

console.log(obj.array[1]);
2

console.log(typeof obj);
object

console.log(typeof obj.array);
object

var a =[1,2,3];
console.log(typeof a);
object
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first answer is linked to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996871/why-does-typeof-array-with-objects-return-object-and-not-array)

For the second part

> and use it like array ?

**IF** you receive an array as key in the json data, and if the format is correct, you can extract the value and use it right away without worrying about anything else. Which is basically `obj.classId[index];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
var obj = {PhaseId: "", OptionDescription: "", PhaseDescription: "", 
           ClassId: ['test','test1'] };

console.log(Array.isArray(obj.ClassId)); // return true
```

You can iterate using array methods like this:

```
var obj = {PhaseId: "", OptionDescription: "", PhaseDescription: "", 
           ClassId: ['test','test1'] };

// log array each element to the console
obj.ClassId.forEach( i => console.log(i));

// create a new array
var array0 = obj.ClassId.map( i => i );

// log array0 to the console
console.log(array0);

var array1 = obj.ClassId.map(i => i + ' passed ' );

// log array1 to the console
console.log(array1);
```

Depends what you want to do with an array or what to get from an array You are using special array method:

[Array Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: I just don't need to compare but i need to iterate over it like array.

Comment: Please review my last edit, and if it isn't what You are looking for, please specify what You are iterating for, what you want to achieve so anyone  can issue a solution to Your specific problem . Basically you ca access every element of an object by object.objectProperty.methodForthisProperty(set of params, function(){}, ect );