# Flattening Arrays using javascript join, and json.parse

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have nested array like this,

```
var a=[1,2,[3,4,[5,6]]];
```

I am trying to convert it to flatten array.

```
var a=[1,2,[3,4,[5,6]]];
var b = a.join(',');
console.log(b);
var c = JSON.parse("[" + b + "]")
console.log(typeof c);
```

I used join and JSON.parse() methods, I am able to convert to a flat array, but when I do typeof for the array 'c', it says the type as 'object but not an array. My question is as everything is considered as an 'Object' in Javascript. Is returning the array 'c' as 'object' is correct or not?

Comment: Use flat: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does typeof array with objects return "Object" and not "Array"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996871/why-does-typeof-array-with-objects-return-object-and-not-array)

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are a type of `object` which is why it is printing **object** to the console. To test if an array is an array you need to use `Array.isArray(someVar)`.

**Note:** You can use [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the array.

```js
let a = [1,2,[3,4,[5,6]]]

// 2 is the depth
console.log(a.flat(2))

console.log(typeof a)

// Prints true
console.log(Array.isArray(a))
// Prints false
console.log(Array.isArray({a:123}))
// Prints false
console.log(Array.isArray(123))
// Prints false
console.log(Array.isArray('Kitty'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The best method you can use to check if `c` is an array is **[Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)**, and it gives `true` for `c` so you are "safe":

```js
var a=[1,2,[3,4,[5,6]]];
var b = a.join(',');
var c = JSON.parse("[" + b + "]");

console.log(c);
console.log("c is Array?: " + Array.isArray(c));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

And yes, it is ok the `typeof` for an array gives `object` because from **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Description)**:

> Arrays are **list-like objects** whose prototype has methods to perform traversal and mutation operations...

```js
var a=[1,2,[3,4,[5,6]]];
console.log(typeof a);

var b = new Array(10);
console.log(typeof b);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Now, if you need to flatten your array, you can use the experimental **[Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)** it takes and optional `deep` argument (default to `1`). However note this method can not be available on some browser/version. In this, can you can use the next version with recursion:

```js
const flattenDeep = (arr) =>
{
   return arr.reduce(
       (acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val),
       []
   );
}

console.log(flattenDeep([1,2,[3,4,[5,6]]]));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively flatten the array with reduce like this. If the item inside the array is `an array`, flatten the array with the same function.

```js
const flatten = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc,item) => {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      return acc.concat(flatten(item))
    }
    return acc.concat(item)
  }, [])
}

const a = [1,2,[3,4,[5,6]]];
console.log(flatten(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
obj instanceof Array
```

Also something to consider -- if you're passing the Array across frame boundaries, you will need to do the following:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]'
```

See related post: [How to detect if a variable is an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058427/how-to-detect-if-a-variable-is-an-array)