# How to use Array.protoype.map() on array of objects to filter out some specific keys based on it's values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have the following array of objects, in which some specific keys have a value which is either a string or an array. I want to get the keys with string values as it is and remove "NA" from keys with array values.

I am trying to achieve the same by doing .map method on the array, check the type of the value of each key in the data object, if an array then use .filter to remove the "NA" values.

```
var dataArr = [
    {
     a: 'foo',
     b: [1, 2, "NA", "NA", 3],
     c: ["NA", 6]
    },
    {
     a: 'bar',
     b: ["NA", "NA", "NA"],
     c: []
    }
];
dataArr.map(dataObj => {
    for (let key in dataObj) {
        if (key !== 'a')
            dataObj[key] = dataObj[key].filter(val => { if(val != "NA") return val})
    }
    return dataObj;
});
```

The above block of code works as expected but I want a better and future-proof solution. Moreover, this looks bad too.

Comment: Your current code is *mutating* the original `dataArr`, is that really desirable?

Comment: `dataArr[0].map` will not work. You're using map on JS Object. Objects don't have map function.

Comment: @Shubham thanks for pointing out, it's a typo. I am editing the question.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, I am aware of the mutation issue, thanks for pointing out. But mutation won't make any impact here since I am cleaning up the unwanted values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to update the original array, you could loop through the array using `forEach`. Then loop through each object's keys using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and check if it is an array using [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray). Update the property after [filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the `NA` value

```js
const dataArr = [{a:'foo',b:[1,2,"NA","NA",3],c:["NA",6]},{a:'bar',b:["NA","NA","NA"],c:[]}];

dataArr.forEach(o => {
  for (const key in o) {
    if (Array.isArray(o[key]))
      o[key] = o[key].filter(s => s !== "NA")
  }
})

console.log(dataArr)
```

If you want to get a new array without mutating the original objects, you can use `map` like this:

```js
const dataArr = [{a:'foo',b:[1,2,"NA","NA",3],c:["NA",6]},{a:'bar',b:["NA","NA","NA"],c:[]}];

const newArray = dataArr.map(o => {
  const newObj = {};
  
  for (const key in o) {
    if (Array.isArray(o[key]))
      newObj[key] = o[key].filter(s => s !== "NA")
    else
      newObj[key] = o[key]
  }
  
  return newObj;
})

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using nested `map()` and `filter()`

- First of all use `map()` on the main array.
- Then get the entries of each object using `Object.entries()`
- Then use `map()` on the entries of each object.
- Return the value as it is if the `Array.isArray` is `false` otherwise return the filtered value of array.
- Finally use `Object.fromEntries()` to make an object.

```js
var dataArr = [
    {
     a: 'foo',
     b: [1, 2, "NA", "NA", 3],
     c: ["NA", 6]
    },
    {
     a: 'bar',
     b: ["NA", "NA", "NA"],
     c: []
    }
];

const res = dataArr.map(x => 
               Object.fromEntries(
                   Object.entries(x)
                     .map(([k,v]) => 
                        [k,Array.isArray(v) ? v.filter(b => b !== "NA") : v])
                     )
               )

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I don't think it solves the time complexity issue.

Comment: @SibasishMohanty You haven't mentioned anything regarding time complexity in the question. What is problem with time complexity?

Comment: Just wondering, if I could achieve better time complexity since the number of keys is in the range of thousands for each object.

Answer (score 1):

Use `for...of` on the object's entries. For each entry check if it's an array. If it's an array filter, and then assign to the new object. If not, assign without filtering. This will not mutate the original array.

```js
const dataArr = [{"a":"foo","b":[1,2,"NA","NA",3],"c":["NA",6]},{"a":"bar","b":["NA","NA","NA"],"c":[]}]

const result = dataArr.map(dataObj => {
  const filterObject = {};
  
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(dataObj)) {
    filterObject[key] = Array.isArray(val) ?
      dataObj[key].filter(val => val != 'NA')
      :
      val;
  }
  
  return filterObject;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const dataArr = [{
            a: 'foo',
            b: [1, 2, "NA", "NA", 3],
            c: ["NA", 6]
        },
        {
            a: 'bar',
            b: ["NA", "NA", "NA"],
            c: []
        }
    ];

    const res = dataArr.map((obj) => {
        for(let i in obj){
            if(Array.isArray(obj[i])){
                obj[i] = obj[i].filter(el=>el!=="NA")
            }
        }
        return obj;
    });

    console.log('@>res', res)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the number of keys in my object is too many to check all their values individually.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will be a better code refactor,pls provide with the desired output also:

```
dataArr.forEach(object=>{
  for (let value in object){
   let isArr = Object.prototype.toString.call(data) == '[object Array]';
   isArr? object[value] = object[value].filter(val => {return val != "NA"}):null}
 })
```

Comment: `typeof` array is `"object"` too.

Comment: I have edited the  solution pls check it out,referenced from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996871/why-does-typeof-array-with-objects-return-object-and-not-array