# If javascript arrays are objects, then does it have a key:value pair?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

If JavaScript Arrays are a special implementation of Objects, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996871/why-does-typeof-array-with-objects-return-object-and-not-array) , then are the key value pairs the index of that element and the element itself?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Arrays are special objects that have numeric keys and a `length` property. As well as inheriting from the Array prototype.

Comment: Just try it - questions like these should be investigated, not posted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can be quickly confirmed using Chrome's dev tools console.

Comment: @VLAZ: correction, they have _string_ keys, like everything else.

Comment: @georg OK, sure, I can see why this might be misleading. All keys are indeed strings (except symbols) but JS does have special consideration if the string contains a positive number. So usually "numeric keys" refers to "keys that are strings but contain numbers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have built in global class called Object which is starting point in a prototype chain in other words it is top most node in prototypes.

We can check the value of key and values for any object like-

Object.keys(["a", "b", "c"]);

// Output

["0", "1", "2"]

```
0: "0"
1: "1"
2: "2"
length: 3
```

Same for values

Object.values(["a", "b", "c"]);

// Output
["a", "b", "c"]

```
0: "a"
1: "b"
2: "c"
length: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can verify it for example with [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), which returns key value pairs of an object:

```
Object.entries(["a", "b", "c"])

// Output
0: (2) ["0", "a"]
1: (2) ["1", "b"]
2: (2) ["2", "c"]
```

Comment: Edited the example to use letters as values. It's a bit easier to read than if everything was (almost) the same number.

Answer (score -3):

Other way with Map. Refer below URL for more information.
https://javascript.info/keys-values-entries

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

```
const iterable = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]);

for (const entry of iterable) {
  console.log(entry);
}
// ['a', 1]
// ['b', 2]
// ['c', 3]

for (const [key, value] of iterable) {
  console.log(value);
}
```