# Iterate through an array with a single index that contains multiple objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have some data that looks like this

```
let arr = [
  {
    a:1,
    b:2,
    c:3
  },
  {
    a:4,
    b:5,
    c:6
  },
  {
    a:7,
    b:8,
    c:9
  }
]
```

and I'd like to get it to reformat like this

```
{
   a: [1,4,7],
   b: [2,5,8],
   c: [3,6,9]
}
```

Here is my solution:

```
let arr = [
  {
    a:1,
    b:2,
    c:3
  },
  {
    a:4,
    b:5,
    c:6
  },
  {
    a:7,
    b:8,
    c:9
  }
]

// {
//   a: [1,4,7],
//   b: [2,5,8],
//   c: [3,6,9]
// }

function practice (arr) {
  console.log(typeof arr) // WHY IS THIS RETURNING AN OBJECT???
  let keys = Object.keys(arr[0])
  const resultObj = {}
  for (let key of keys) {
    resultObj[key] = []
  }
  arr.forEach((x,idx)=> {
    for (let key in x) {
      resultObj[key].push(x[key])
    }
  })
    return resultObj
}

practice(arr)
```

I know that my solution is not the most efficient method. While I completed the exercise, I am having trouble understanding the concepts below:

- At first glance, `arr` to me seems like **an array with a single index
  containing three objects**. For example, `arr[0] = {obj1},{obj2},{obj3}`, but
  I performed a `typeof` check on `arr` and it returned object.
- When I console log `arr` at a specified index `arr[1]`, it prints out `{a:4,b:5,c:6}` as if it is an array.
- My question is what is happening here and what exactly is this type of data structure?

Please offer me a more clean and efficient code to this question and explain to me the concepts.

Comment: Post your code here, not elsewhere.

Comment: For the array check, you should use Array.isArray

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12996879/5385381

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function practice (arr) {
  let resultObj = {};

  arr.forEach((x) => {
    for (let key in x) {
      if (resultObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        resultObj[key].push(x[key]);
      } else {
        resultObj[key] = [x[key]];
      }
    }
  });

  return resultObj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to check for an array, you should make use of `Array.isArray()` method. typeof will give you an object since Array is essentially a form of object in javascript created using the Object constructor.

To get a desired output, all you need to do is to loop over the array and store the values in an object

```js
let arr = [
  {
    a:1,
    b:2,
    c:3
  },
  {
    a:4,
    b:5,
    c:6
  },
  {
    a:7,
    b:8,
    c:9
  }
]

var res = {};
arr.forEach((obj) => {
   Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
      if(res[key]) {
         res[key].push(val);
      } else {
         res[key] = [val];
      }
   })
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use array [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method for this like:

- Loop through all the keys of each object in the array using `Object.keys(o)` inside the `reduce()` method
- Inside the loop, initialize the accumulator with the same key as we have inside the loop and the initial value of that key as empty array `[]`.
- Then using `r[k].push(o[k])`, we are adding the matching key values inside this array.
- Then finally return the object `r` from the `.reduce()` method.

```js
let arr = [{a:1,b:2,c:3},{a:4,b:5,c:6},{a:7,b:8,c:9}];
const res = arr.reduce((r, o) => {
  Object.keys(o).forEach((k) => {
    r[k] = r[k] || [];
    r[k].push(o[k])
  });
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```js
let arr = [
  {
    a:1,
    b:2,
    c:3
  },
  {
    a:4,
    b:5,
    c:6
  },
  {
    a:7,
    b:8,
    c:9
  }
];

let res = {};

Object.values(arr).forEach(value => {
  Object.keys(value).forEach(key => {
   if (typeof res[key] === 'undefined') {
     res[key] = [];
   }
   res[key].push(value[key])
  })
})


console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

With multiple `forEach` loops build an Object with the keys and value are merged for same key.

```js
let arr = [
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  },
  {
    a: 4,
    b: 5,
    c: 6
  },
  {
    a: 7,
    b: 8,
    c: 9
  }
];

const res = {};
arr.forEach(item => {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(
    key => (res[key] = key in res ? [...res[key], item[key]] : [item[key]])
  );
});

console.log(res);
```