# How to merge two arrays with new property in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to merge two arrays in javascript.I tried but not working. How to add new property like details and how to merge in single array

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-6cfbaw

Example:

```
var array1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Zohn",
  },
];

var array2 = [
  {
    name: "Zohn",
    address: "Test1",
  },
  {
    name: "Zohn Peter",
    address: "Test2",
  },
  {
    name: "Peter Mark",
    address: "Test3",
  },
];

var array3 = [...array1, ...array2];
```

Output array3 should be :

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Zohn",
    details: [
      {
        name: "Zohn Zeo",
        address: "Test1",
      },
      {
        name: "Zohn Peter",
        address: "Test2",
      },
      {
        name: "Peter Mark",
        address: "Test3",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: Are you actually trying to merge arrays or just take an object in the first array and create a new property that holds the second array? Meaning `array1[0].details = array2`?

Comment: Do you want just `array1[0].details = array2`?

Comment: You are not merging the arrays, but simply assignins `arr2` to a property in `arr1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to merge the arrays, you are just adding an attribute to the first element of `array1`.

```js
var array1 = [
  {
    id:1,
    name:"Zohn" 
  }
]

var array2 = [
  { 
    name:"Zohn",
    address:"Test1" 
  },
  { 
    name:"Zohn Peter",
    address:"Test2"  
  },
  { 
    name:"Peter Mark",
    address:"Test3"  
  }
]

array1[0]['details'] = array2

console.log(array1)
```

Comment: Getting     console.log(typeof(array1));   console.log(typeof(array2));   are object
 object

Comment: So How to convert to array and merge?

Comment: Despite what `console.log()` says, `array1` and `array2` are arrays. You can read about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996871/why-does-typeof-array-with-objects-return-object-and-not-array) and see how to verify that they are arrays. There is no need to convert, and no need to merge.

Comment: Getting  ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'details' of undefined

Comment: Hm, not sure why that is. Can you show me the code you are using?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this piece of code helps you.

```js
var array1 =[];
var itemOfArray= {
    id:1,
    name:"Zohn" ,
    details: [ ]
  };

var array2 = [
  { 
    name:"Zohn",
    address:"Test1" 
  },
  { 
    name:"Zohn Peter",
    address:"Test2"  
  },
  { 
    name:"Peter Mark",
    address:"Test3"  
  }
]

itemOfArray['details']=array2;
array1.push(itemOfArray);

console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example

```js
var array1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Zohn",
  },
];

var array2 = [
  {
    name: "Zohn",
    address: "Test1",
  },
  {
    name: "Zohn Peter",
    address: "Test2",
  },
  {
    name: "Peter Mark",
    address: "Test3",
  },
];

const output = array1.map((entry) => ({ ...entry, details: [...array2] }));

console.dir(output, { depth: null, color: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge details, you have to keep a reference for each record of array1 in array2 and then merge as shown below.

```js
var array1=[
{
  id:1,
  name:"Zohn" 
}
];

var array2=[
{ 
  array1Id: 1,
  name:"Zohn",
  address:"Test1" 
},
{ 
  array1Id: 1,
  name:"Zohn Peter",
  address:"Test2"  
},
{ 
  array1Id: 1,
  name:"Peter Mark",
  address:"Test3"  
}
];

var array3 = [];

array1.forEach((entry) => {
  array3.push(
    {
      id: entry.id,
      name: entry.name,
      details: array2.filter((value) => {
        return value.array1Id == entry.id;
      })
    }
  );
});

console.log(array3);
```

Comment: Getting console.log(typeof(array1)); console.log(typeof(array2)); are object; object

Comment: So How to convert to array and merge?

Comment: Basically, arrays are also objects in js. That's why its returning object. But, you can use it as an array.