# Why my array inside a my code implicitly becoming an object. I am declaring an ARRAY and it's returning and object type

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

[image: Here is the code]

So there is the issue  I am declaring an array but it's implicitly changing into an object. I can't understand why?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: It's not changing into an object, array is an object...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does typeof array with objects return "object" and not "array"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996871/why-does-typeof-array-with-objects-return-object-and-not-array)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript array is an object: `The JavaScript Array class is a global object that is used in the construction of arrays; which are high-level, list-like objects.`

Source: [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)