# While accessing JSON attribute inside of event handler in react I get undefined

Tags: reactjs

I've got my event handler for clicking on a list. And i get weird behavior because, i can access all the state elements, but I get some weird stuff after trying to access atribute inside of this state element.

```
  handleCardClick(player, i) {
    const player_card = this.state.player_cards[player][i]
    const board_card = this.state.cardsOnTable.slice(-1)
    console.log(board_card, player_card)
    console.log(typeof board_card, typeof player_card)
    console.log(board_card.value, player_card.value, board_card.suit, player_card.suite)
    if(this.canBePlayed(board_card, player_card)) {
      let player_cards = this.state.player_cards.slice();
      player_cards[player][i].chosen = !player_cards[player][i].chosen
      this.setState({player_cards: player_cards})
    } else {
      return undefined
    }
  }
```

And here is response from console
For `console.log(board_card, player_card)`:

```
{
    "value": "4",
    "suit": "spades",
    "chosen": false
}
{
    "value": "5",
    "suit": "hearts",
    "chosen": false
}
```

For `console.log(board_card, player_card)`:
`object object`

For `console.log(board_card.value, player_card.value, board_card.suit, player_card.suite)`: `undefined "5" undefined undefined`

And i would like to have from last log something like: `"4" "5" "spades" "hearts"`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`slice()` function return another array not object but on console it will show object. so that's why your board_card.value and suit returned undefined then in the case of player_card.suite spelling not correct actually in player_card it is suit. 
For your reference

1. [Check this previous Question : Type of array return object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996871/why-does-typeof-array-with-objects-return-object-and-not-array)
2. [Mozilla doc: Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: Oh that's right, it was stupid mistakes, thanks