# Unable to convert jquery ajax response to array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, knockout.js

I have an API which returns an array of format:

```
[
  {
    "abc": "def",
    "efg": "hij"
  },
  {
    "abc": "def",
    "efg": "hij"
  }
]
```

When I hit the service with jquery.ajax I am able to get a response

```
$.ajax({
url: URL,
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'JSON',
xhrFields: {
withCredentials: false
},
success: function (data) {
console.log(data);
},
error: function (request, error) {});
```

On java script when I try to check the data type of data it is of type Object.
When I directly print data on console

```
0: Object { "abc": "def", "egf":"ghi " }​​
​
1: Object { "abc": "def", "egf":"ghi " }​​
```

Where as when I print with knockout.toJSON(data) or JSON.stringify(data) it returns

```
[
  {
    "abc": "def",
    "efg": "hij"
  },
  {
    "abc": "def",
    "efg": "hij"
  }
]
```

However I am unable to convert the response into array as I want it to be an array.

I even tried JSON.parse on the knockout.JSON(data), JSON.stringify(data), and directly on data but it fails.

What is the best way to convert this to an array.

Comment: The response ***is*** an array. there is no conversion needed. Seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346503/what-is-the-opposite-of-the-xy-problem) - you're trying to do something, it doesn't work, and you assume this data is not an array, therefore you ask how to make it one. What is the problem you're trying to solve and why does this array not work for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS has [**primitive**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) data types and `Objects`,since `Array` is not a primitive its `typeof` will return `Object`.

You can treat your response as an array in your code,no conversion is needed.

[Study this SO post for further info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996871/why-does-typeof-array-with-objects-return-object-and-not-array) and [the docs about JS data types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)