# JSON Data Handling in JavaScript: Parsing and Redundancy

Tags: reactjs, json

I have a question with this code, what is working for me is converting to a string with JSON.stringify and then parsing with JSON.parse. Am I doing something redundant?

```
 const notificationsDataCleaned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(notificationsData))
 const Notifications:ActorNotification[] = (notificationsDataCleaned).map((notification:Partial<Notification>)=>{
          //console.log(notification)
          return { 
            ID: notification.ID,
            MESSAGE_TITLE: notification.MESSAGE_TITLE
           }
        }).sort((a:CitizenNotification,b:CitizenNotification)=>(new Date(b.CREATED_AT).getTime() - new Date(a.CREATED_AT).getTime()));
```

That code runs fine but as you can see I making a JSON.stringify and then a parse. But if I make just a parse, like this:

```
const notificationsDataCleaned = JSON.parse((notificationsData))
    const Notifications:ActorNotification[] = (notificationsDataCleaned).map((notification:Partial<Notification>)=>{
      //console.log(notification)
      return { 
        ID: notification.ID,
        MESSAGE_TITLE: notification.MESSAGE_TITLE
       }
    }).sort((a:CitizenNotification,b:CitizenNotification)=>(new Date(b.CREATED_AT).getTime() - new Date(a.CREATED_AT).getTime()));
```

that code returns:

> VM117:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'o',
> "[object Obj"... is not valid JSON
> at JSON.parse ()

And the last one

```
const notificationsDataCleaned = ((notificationsData))
const Notifications:ActorNotification[] = (notificationsDataCleaned).map((notification:Partial<Notification>)=>{
          //console.log(notification)
          return { 
            ID: notification.ID,
            MESSAGE_TITLE: notification.MESSAGE_TITLE
           }
        }).sort((a:CitizenNotification,b:CitizenNotification)=>(new Date(b.CREATED_AT).getTime() - new Date(a.CREATED_AT).getTime()));
```

returns:

```
The property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

So, What's notificationsData, well If I make:

```
console.log("This is notificationsData: "+JSON.stringify(notificationsData))
console.log("This is notificationsData type: "+ typeof (notificationsData))
```

I get:

> This is notificationsData: [{"ID":"224","MESSAGE_TITLE":"Some
> title"},{"ID":"141","MESSAGE_TITLE":"Other title"}]
>
> This is notificationsData type: object

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(notificationsData))`? All it does is create a copy but since your code doesn't modify `notificationsDataCleaned` you could just use `notificationsData` instead.

Comment: @Nick but if I just use notificationsData it returns that The property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'. The problem here is that notificationsData is not an string.

Comment: I don't see how that can be, since in your `console.log` of the `typeof notificationsData` you get `object` and so that should also apply to `notificationsDataCleaned`. Have you tried logging `notificationsDataCleaned` value and type?

Answer (score 0):

- `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` is not redundunt as it is one way to create a [deep copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy) of `notificationsData` array

in this particaular case, you don't need it as `.map()` returns a new copy of the `array`

`const Notifications:ActorNotification[] = notificationsData.map((...`  should work the same way ( unless you're using `notificationsDataCleaned`  somewhere else )

- this `const notificationsDataCleaned = JSON.parse((notificationsData))` errors ecause `JSON.parse()` takes a `string` as an argument and `notificationsData` is not a `string`
- `notificationsData` is an [Array Oject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12996879/7328218)
- `The property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.` i'm not sure where this is coming from but my guess is you tried `const notificationsDataCleaned = JSON.stringify((notificationsData))` then `notificationsDataCleaned.map()` :P

Comment: thanks but also notificationsData.map returns The property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'. The problem here is that notificationsData is not an string, So, what's happening? it's because is object and not object array?